# iOS Archive failing on Xamarin Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have upgraded my Visual Studio to 17.5.3 recently. With this version of VS, iOS archive is failing with below error:

> Package 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.6' was restored using
> '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETStandard,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

This issue happening with only Visual Studio 17.5.3. Didn't see this issue with earlier versions of VS.

Can someone please suggest on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

> '.NETStandard,Version=v2.1'. This package may not be fully compatible
> with your project.

Your app or the third library included in your app should have used some package which is based on '.NETStandard,Version=v2.1'，which may not be fully compatible with your project.

You can try to update the nugets in your app to the latest version.

Besides,I noticed that nuget [Microsoft.Bcl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl#versions-body-tab) has been deprecated as part of the .NET Package Deprecation effort and is no longer maintained. I recommend not using this nuget again.